# How do you set an AddIn button's Help source and topicID values at runtime?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, add-in

I would like a way to dynamically set the help source/topicID for a button.

[Example Snippet:](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000004n7000000)

```
  <Button
    id="Acme_FullExtent"
    class="FullExtent"
    caption="Full Extent"
    tip="Zooms the map the the full extent."
    category="Acme"
    image="Images\FullExtent.png">
    <Help source="http://www.Acme.com/help.htm" topicID="SectionB"/>
  </Button>
```

More background: I need to link the button's F1 help to online Help that is published by someone else and which is a configuration nightmare for various levels of testing (e.g.Test, UAT vs Production). I like the idea of loosely coupled online AddIn help content, but the help content still needs to be tightly coupled with the appropriate environment (which is defined via configuration at runtime).

I suppose the fallback plan is to compile the help into a chm (like pre-10.1 AddIns) and carry that onboard the AddIn.